# Send click to custom control in applet window

Tags: c, winapi

Would it be possible send a click message using SendMessage to a control in parent window?

Apparently, the following doesn't seem to be working

```
SendMessage(hParent, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(x, y));
SendMessage(hParent, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, MAKELPARAM(x, y));

//x and y are location of child control on parent applet window.
```

Answer (score 0):

you are sending the message to the parent not to the control in the parent window
if you known the id you can get the handle with

```
GetDlgItem(hParent, id)
```